# Value should be in between the value of two columns

Tags: mysql, comparison

assuming that i have a table of:

```
ID    (int)
Date1 (date)
Date2 (date)
```

how can i query for rows where `x` is greater than or equal to `Date1` but also less than or equal to `Date2` ?

i currently have this where clause:

```
(
    Date1 <= DATE(NOW()) --just an example
AND 
    Date2 >= DATE(NOW()) --just an example
)
```

but does not return any rows at all, although when i try either:

```
Date1 <= DATE(NOW()) --just an example
```

or

```
Date2 >= DATE(NOW()) --just an example
```

it works, what i need is both comparison operators but in a single line, i think my logic is similar to `BETWEEN ... AND ...` its just that `Date1` and `Date2` is in the `BETWEEN` and `AND` operator

Exam Scenario:

```
ID          Date1          Date2
1           10-16-2016     10-30-2016
```

when i run,

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `mytable` 
WHERE
    DATE('10/10/16') BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2;
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `mytable` 
WHERE
(
     DATE('10/10/16') >= Date1
AND 
    DATE('10/10/16') <= Date2
);
```

it returns no row, but when `DATE('10/10/16') >= Date1` and `DATE('10/10/16') <= Date2` are run separately, results are returned.

Comment: You say you have results when you use `Date1 <= DATE(NOW())` and `Date2 >= DATE(NOW())` separate. This sounds like you do not have `Date1 <= DATE(NOW()) AND Date2 >= DATE(NOW())` for any record. Can you post some sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
select *
from my_table
where x >= Date1
and x <= Date1
```

I removed parenthesis from your last query, and works in my case. If you still not getting result, maybe your data doesn't have any matching rows.